# when a key is located on more than one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'd like to know what am I doing wrong on this exercise where SectionID is a key on table RestaurantSection and a foreign key on RestaurantTable.

```
SELECT RestaurantName, Street, City, State, SectionID
FROM   RestaurantSection, RestaurantTable
WHERE RestaurantSection.SectionID = RestaurantTable.SectionID
AND     Restaurant.State = "NY"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error message, you would probably see that it says something like ambiguous reference to `SectionID`.

When writing queries, you should:

- Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column names.
- Probably give your tables aliases.

So, something like this (I am guessing where the columns come from):

```
SELECT rs.RestaurantName, rs.Street, rs.City, rs.State, rs.SectionID
FROM RestaurantSection as rs INNER JOIN
     RestaurantTable as rt
     ON rs.SectionID = rt.SectionID
WHERE rs.State = "NY";
```